# Qml restore minimized window

Tags: qt, qml

Qt 5.11.1 & Qt Creator 4.7.0, Windows 10

Create a maximized window, click the button (use `showMinimized()` or `visibility = Window.Minimized`) to minimized it.

Then click the application icon in taskbar, the window supposed to show maximized. But, it's always windowed instead of maximized.

If I click the system "minimize button" top-right corner, the window can restore to maximized.

main.qml:

```
import QtQuick 2.9
import QtQuick.Controls 2.2
import QtQuick.Window 2.3

Window {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480

    Component.onCompleted: showMaximized()

    Button {
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        onClicked: {
            showMinimized()
            // visibility = Window.Minimized
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Seems behavior differ depend on OS or Qt version. In Windows 7 and Qt 5.9.2 it restored exactly as it looked like before minimizing. If it was windowed it restored windowed, if it was maximized it restored maximized.

Comment: Just tried Qt 5.9.2  Windows 10 behaves exactly as supposed. Maybe issue of latest Qt version?

Comment: seems bug of Qt, not fixed currently. ref https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-69711